# transfer a part of a string into hashed value

Tags: php

is there any way to hash a part of a string. For example I have a file called "abc.jpg", can i have the letters before the ".jpg" hash ?
1st file is upload_form.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500"/>
   <input type="file" name="pix" size="60"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

the second file is upload_file.php

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   include("form_upload.php");
 }
 else
 {
  //if file is too large too upload
   if($_FILES['pix']['tmp_name']=="")
    {
     echo "<p>file is too large too upload, Please make sure the file you want to upload is smaller than 5MB</p>";
     include("form_upload.inc");
     exit();
    }
    //if the file is not jpeg format
   if(!preg_match("/^image\/jpeg$/",$_FILES['pix']['type']))
    {
     echo "<p>only jpg file is accepted !</p>";
     include("form_upload.inc");
     exit();
    }
    // if everything is ok
    else
    {
     $destination='C:\xampp\htdocs\test\my_application\picture\ '.$_FILES['pix']['name'];
     $tmp_file=$_FILES['pix']['tmp_name'];
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$destination);
     echo "<p>picture was upload successfully</p>";
     echo "<p>Name :{$_FILES['pix']['name']}</p>";
     echo "<p>Size {$_FILES['pix']['size']}</p>";
     echo "<p>Type {$_FILES['pix']['type']}</p>";
     echo "<img src='picture/ {$_FILES['pix']['name']}' alt='picture'/>";
    }
 }
?>
```

I want to to transfer the picture name into md5 values but only the name not the ".jpg". Is there any way to do that

Comment: the picture name is a string, so cut the string with substr with negative values. like -4

Comment: "`preg_match("/^image\/jpeg$/",$_FILES['pix']['type'])`". Why? `$_FILES['pix']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'` would work just as fine? Why include regex? Also, check `pathinfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$hash = md5(basename($_FILES['pix']['name'], '.jpg')) . '.jpg';
```

if you know that the extension is `.jpg`.

You can also get the extension by exploding on the dot and taking the last element of the generated array (just an example, you can also use a regex or whatever):

```
$ext = '.' . end(explode('.', $_FILES['pix']['name']));
$hash = md5(basename($_FILES['pix']['name'], $ext)) . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

thankyou I have find another way it is adding a string ".jpg" after the hashed value.